# DLL load failed while importing _netCDF4 in Python

Tags: python, netcdf4

I am trying to download and plot NCAR reanalysis data that requires importing the netCDF4 module. Here is the link to a python program similar to mine used to plot this NCAR .nc data below.
https://geoclimatologyblog.wordpress.com/2016/04/24/plot-highs-and-lows-in-a-ncepncar-reanalysis-slp-file-with-python/

Here is my program below and what I do not understand is that I DO have netcdf4 installed in my environment and I have created a new environment loading python 3.8.16 from scratch, xarray, netcdf4, and pandas AND I still get this error. Please help, thank you.

```
import os
os.environ["PROJ_LIB"] = 'C:\\Users\\Yury\\anaconda3\\Library\\share'
from sys import exit
#import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray as xr
import cartopy.crs as ccrs


#https://psl.noaa.gov/repository/entry/show?entryid=synth%3Ae570c8f9-ec09-4e89-93b4-babd5651e7a9%3AL25jZXAucmVhbmFseXNpcy5kZXJpdmVkL3N1cmZhY2Uvc2xwLm1vbi5tZWFuLm5j
# Download the dataset from above url
#url = 'https://rda.ucar.edu/thredds/fileServer/ds083.2/pressure/mon-anom/slp.mon.ltm.nc'
#file_path = '//PORFILER03.ar.local/gtdshare/IDL/wtypes/data_NCEP_slp/slp.mon.mean.nc'
file_path = 'C:/Users/U321103/Downloads/mslp.mon.mean.nc'
with open(file_path,'r')as file:
    dataset = xr.open_dataset(file_path)
```

My error:

```
runfile('//porfiler03.ar.local/gtdshare/VORTEX/MONTHLY_VARIABILITY/scripts/NCAR_Get_MSLP_USA_WORKING_MONTHLY.py', wdir='//porfiler03.ar.local/gtdshare/VORTEX/MONTHLY_VARIABILITY/scripts')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\Maps\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File \\porfiler03.ar.local\gtdshare\vortex\monthly_variability\scripts\ncar_get_mslp_usa_working_monthly.py:23
    dataset = xr.open_dataset(file_path)

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\Maps\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\api.py:539 in open_dataset
    backend_ds = backend.open_dataset(

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\Maps\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\netCDF4_.py:572 in open_dataset
    store = NetCDF4DataStore.open(

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\Maps\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\netCDF4_.py:343 in open
    import netCDF4

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\Maps\lib\site-packages\netCDF4\__init__.py:3
    from ._netCDF4 import *

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _netCDF4: The specified procedure could not be found.
```